# How to define a Module that is a function in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm looking for a way to write a valid definition file for [debug](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug)

In JS you call:

```
var debug = require('debug')('http')
```

Then you use it like:

```
debug('my debug message');
```

I have no clue how to define my debug.d.ts to support that pattern. Any help is wellcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For use in TypeScript you'll have to separate out the call into two parts like so:

```
import debugMod = require('debug');
var debug = debugMod('http');
```

The definition file (`debug.d.ts`) would look like this:

```
declare module "debug" {
    function dbg(s:string):(s:string) => void;

    export = dbg;
}
```

Comment: Fixed your answer. Was almost right, the desclare was missing. Thanks. Seems to work now.